# Why am I getting syntax error in Macro in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use macro to change "a123" to "123" in 4 cells by replacing "a" with blank. It's a simple operation. But I seem to be getting a syntax error and this is for all my macros. My settings seem fine. I don't know what's the problem.

Code is showing as follows:

```
Range("B1:B4").Select
. := "a", :="", := xlPart, :=xlByRows, := FALSE, := FALSE, := FALSE
Range("C8").Select
End SUB
```

Comment: This is no valid VBA syntax: `. := "a", :="", := xlPart, :=xlByRows, := FALSE, := FALSE, := FALSE`. Check out how the syntax of the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) should be.

Comment: Yeah, why is it coming in the wrong format? That is my issue. I'm unable to use macro to record because of it

Comment: If you recorded a macro and it came out like this, you have a corrupt install of Office. I recommend to re-install Office completely.

Comment: I would also recommend posting all the code from the recording. Its clear you have not posted all the code...

Comment: I have seen this error already before (also see here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/macro-recorder-producing-strange-code-with-syntax-error.899955/) this is caused by a malfunction in Office. I could not find any solution to fix this besides re-install of office.

Comment: I reinstalled the office. It's still not working and giving the same error.

Comment: Well, then something other is interfering. Make sure to deactivate all plugins.